# How to delete an object in Javascript crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, object, prototypal

```
var obj = {
    destroy: function(){this = null;}
};

obj.destroy();
```

This works in Chrome, however firefox is throwing an error referencing this for some reason. Is there a better way to kill this object within a method?

Error:

```
invalid assignment left-hand side
[Break On This Error] destroy: function(){this = null;}
```

Comment: invalid assignment left-hand side
[Break On This Error] destroy: function(){this = null;}

Comment: What is the advantage of having the object encapsulate its destructor? Is obj.destroy() superior to obj=null ?

Comment: You can't (and you shouldn't - ever heard of dangling pointers? Your code would create one if it worked). JavaScript handles memory management for you. This approach is especially broken - go grab a browser in which it "works" and try it: http://jsfiddle.net/BmxVP/ I bet you it alerts 1.

Comment: Sounds like ff wont let you set the object to null. Not sure why though. Instead of a destroy method, why not just do: obj = null?

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Chrome actually. Why not use `delete obj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why Chrome allows for it but you can't assign a value to this.  You can reference this, but you can't assign a value to it.

If you have some array destruction you want to perform you can reference this.myArrayName within your destroy method and free up whatever you're trying to release, but you can't just assign null to this to destroy an instance.

I suppose you could try something like this:

```
var foo = {
    // will nullify all properties/methods of foo on dispose
    dispose: function () { for (var key in this) this[key] = null; }
}

foo.dispose();
```

Pretty much as close as you can get to legally nullifying "this"...

Happy coding.

B

Answer (score 2):

Call me old fashion, but:

```
foo = null;
```

Comment: Wouuldn't `foo = undefined` be more appropriate? I'm not sure, but it makes more sense to me if we want something off the map entirely.

Comment: @CamiloMartin undefined and null mean slightly different things in JavaScript. Undefined implies that a variable is not set: `var a;`. Whereas `null` implies that the variable is more or less empty. But really the differences are minor.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think that setting a variable to `undefined` is the closest thing to deleting it, as it behaves more or less like the `delete` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're making this difficult.  Javascript is a garbage collected language.  All you have to do to allow something to be freed is to make sure there are no more references to it anywhere.

So, if you start with:

```
var obj = {
    data: "foo";
};
```

and now you want to get rid or "free" that object, all you have to do is clear the reference to it with:

```
obj = null;
```

Since there are no longer any references in your code to that data structure that you originally defined and assigned to `obj`, the garbage collector will free it.

An object cannot destroy itself (because other things may have references to it).  You allow it to be freed by removing all references to it.  An object can clear out it's own references to other things, though that is generally not required as removing all references to the object itself will also take care of the references it holds (with the exception of some bugs with circular references between JS and the DOM in certain older browsers - particular IE).

One time when you might explicitly "delete" something is if you have a property on an object that you wish to remove.  So, if you have:

```
var obj = {
    data: "foo",
    count: 4
};
```

And you wish to remove the "data" property, you can do that with this:

```
delete obj.data;
```

of if the property/key was assigned programmatically via a variable like this:

```
var key = "xxx";
obj[key] = "foo";
```

you can remove that key with:

```
delete obj[key];
```